# Slack Send Direct Message to ALL on SLACK (Not group message I want to send individual message

Tags: slack, slack-api

my question is  whether  Slack can Send Direct Message to ALL persons on my group on SLACK (Not group message I want to send an individual message

Answer (score 3):

There is no API method for that, but you can create this functionality easily with a small script.

1. Get all members of a Slack team incl. their user IDs with
   [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)
2. Loop through all active users (ignore the ones with `deleted =
   false`)
3. Send a direct message to each user with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) by
   using their user ID as channel

Be sure though to respect the rate limit of max. 1 message per second or the API will return errors.

Comment: how to implement it on the slack , can you explain it , i am new to it

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh sorry, that is beyong this format. But check out the tutorials on Slack. They are pretty good. https://api.slack.com/tutorials